# Who killed whom in Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, rama, ravana, lakshmana

I need a consolidated list of who killed whom in Ramayana. List should be like this:
Ram - Ravan
Ram - Kumbhkarn
Laksman - Meghanad
Laxman - Atikay
Hanuman - Akshay Kumar

I couldn't find this info at one place.

Answer (score 3):

**Hanuman killed Nikumbha**

> Then, while the roaring **Nikumbha was killed in battle by Hanuma,** there ensued an exceedingly terrific struggle between the enraged Rama and Makaraksha, son of Khara a ruler of demons.
>
> http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga77/yuddha_77_frame.htm

**Sugreeva Killed Virupaksha(son of ravan)**

> Beholding that mighty **Virupaksha killed by Sugreeva,** the army of monkeys and demons together looked like the agitated river of Ganga.Beholding that mighty Virupaksha killed by Sugreeva, the army of monkeys and demons together looked like the agitated river of Ganga.
>
> http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga96/yuddha_96_frame.htm

**Angada killed Narantaka**

> And steed and rider fell o'erthrown.
>   **Narántak's** eyes with fury blazed:
>   His heavy hand on high he raised
>   And struck in savage wrath the head
>   Of **Báli's son**, who reeled and bled,
>   Fainted a moment and no more:
>   Then stronger, fiercer than before
>   Smote with that fist which naught could stay,
>   **And crushed to death** the giant lay.
>
> https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rama/ry465.htm

**Hanuman killed Durmuksha**

> **That Hanuman, who was endowed with an energy similar to the wind, was in no way disturbed by that blow but struck Dhumraksha on the middle of his skull** with his rocky peak.
>   That Dhumraksha, struck by the rocky peak, which shattered all his limbs, soon fell down on the ground like a mountain crumbling.
>   **Seeing Dhumraksha having been killed,** the demons left surviving were frightened of being killled by the monkeys and re entered Lanka.
>
> http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga52/yuddha_52_frame.htm

**Angada killed Vanjdanshtra**

> So Angad, fallen on his knees,
>   Yet gathered strength his sword to seize;
>   And, **severed by the glittering blade,
>   The giant's (Vanjdanshtra) head** on earth was laid.
>
> https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rama/ry453.htm

**Rama killed Kumbhakarna**

> **Having destroyed Kumbhakarna** in battle, that Rama shone in the midst
>   of the army of monkeys, in the same way as the sun shines in the midst
>   of the celestial world, having destroyed darkness, duly getting
>   delivered from the mouth of Rahu.
>
> http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga67/yuddha_67_frame.htm

**Sugreeva killed Mahodhara**

> Even while Mahodara was extracting his sword which had got struck in
>   the shield, Sugreeva severed with his own sword, Mahodara's head,
>   which was adorned with ear-rings and helmet.
>
> http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga97/yuddha_97_frame.htm

**Hanuman killed Trishira**

> Then **Tris'iras** raised high his spear
>   Which chilled the trembling foe with fear
>   And, like a flashing meteor through
>   The air at Hanúmán it flew.
>   The Vánar shunned the threatened stroke,
>   And with strong hands the weapon broke.
>   The giant drew his glittering blade:
>   Dire was the wound the weapon made
>   Deep in the Vánar's ample chest,
>   Who, for a moment sore oppressed,
>   Raised his broad hand, regaining might,
>   And struck the rover of the night.
>   Fierce was the blow: with one wild yell
>   Low on the earth the monster fell,
>   **Hanúmán seized his fallen sword
>   Which served no more its senseless lord,
>   And from the monger triple-necked
>   Smote his huge heads with crowns bedecked.**
>
> https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rama/ry466.htm

**Hanuman killed Mahaparsava**

> Then Mahápárs'va burned with ire; Fierce flashed his eyes with
>   vengeful fire. A moment on the dead he gazed, Then his black mace
>   aloft was raised, And down the mass of iron came That struck and shook
>   the Vánar's frame. Hanúmán's chest was wellnigh crushed, And from his
>   mouth red torrents gushed: Yet served one instant to restore His
>   spirit: from the foe he tore His awful mace, and smote, and laid The
>   giant in the dust dismayed.
>
> https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rama/ry466.htm

**Hanuman killed Akshay**

> Killing that Aksha, possessing a lustre equal to that of Jayanta the son of Indra the lord of celestials and having his eyes resembling blood, the heroic Hanuma** reached the same archy door way again, like Yama the lord of death expecting in a moment any mortal getting destroyed by him.
>
> http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga47/sundara_47_frame.htm

**Lakshamana killed Atikaya**

> Then, that arrow, blazing like fire, made in vain those weapons of
>   wonderful form and taking **Atikaya's head, carried it away.That head**
>   with its diadem, **chopped off by Lakshmana**, quickly fell down on the
>   ground, like a peak of the Himalayan Mountain.
>   http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga71/yuddha_71_frame.htm

**Hanuman killed Akampan**

> Thereafter, showing a great haste in uprooting another tree, **Hanuman struck the head of Akampana the General of demons.**Struck with a tree by that high-souled and enraged Hanuman, that **demon fell down and died.**

http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga56/yuddha_56_frame.htm

**Nila killed prahasta**

> While Prahasta the Army chief of demons was slain in the battle by Nila the foremost among the monkeys, Ravana's army possessing terrible arms took to flight with the speed of a tide.
>   http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga59/yuddha_59_frame.htm**

**Lakshamana killed Meghnath(Indrajit)**

> Hearing Indrajit having been killed and witnessing that arduous act of Lakshmana, their beloved friend in battle, the celestials were gratified and experienced a great rejoice in their minds.
>
> http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga90/yuddha_90_frame.htm

**Rama killed Ravana**

> Roaring shouts of joy, quite rejoiced as they were, and proclaiming **Rama's victory and the killing of Ravana in his hands**, the monkeys behaved like conquerors.

http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga108/yuddha_108_frame.htm

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer

Comment: @SachinVishnoi, if you’re satisfied with this answer please accept by clicking tick mark below the voting arrows. It will show the community that this is the correct answer and this is as per site policy. Also in case you liked the answer please contribute an upvote too by clicking the up-arrow on the answer. It’s a well researched answer.